# Closing chrome notification on MacOS triggers onClicked event

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I have a Chrome Extension, which creates some notifications and listens for `onClicked` event on these notifications.

Everything works fine on Windows 10, but MacOS uses native notifications instead of Chrome ones, and when user clicks on notification's close button, `onClicked` event is triggered, and there is no way to find out if user clicked notification's content or close button in event listener...

Any workaround for this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Check https://crbug.com

Comment: Done: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=853484

But I hoped that someone else came upon this problem before